# Remotely executing a program using 'wmi' of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, remote-access, execute

I am trying to execute a program or application in a remote machine using the `wmi` library. Here is my code that I found through googling:

```
ip = <ipaddress_of_remote>
username = <username_of_remote>
password = <password_of_remote>

try:
    SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
    print ("Establishing connection to %s" %ip)
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
    print ("Connection established")
    process_startup = connection.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
    process_startup.ShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL
    process_id, result = connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine=r"cmd", ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)
    if result == 0:
        print ("Process started successfully: %d" % process_id)
    else:
        raise (RuntimeError, "Problem creating process: %d" % result)

except wmi.x_wmi:
    print ("Your Username and Password of "+getfqdn(ip)+" are wrong.")
```

This code works fine, It establishes connection with the remote machine, also returns the `process_pid` by printing `Process started successfully: pid`.
But it does not actually execute anything in the remote machine. Am I doing something wrong in `connection.Win32_Process.Create()`?

I actually wanted to execute a python script using this code. I am trying with launching the command prompt in this code. Please provide the command to execute the python script in the remote machine.